# Excel filter calendar values from data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Attached screenshot has data which is A11:C17 and week calendar B4:H6. I want to match calendar dates from data and showing all activities for that date to calendar cells. For sample, I have put manually E6,F6 and G6 but I want to know how to achieve using excel scripts ie. match the calendar date to data table and concatenate all activities to calendar cell next to date.
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use TEXTJOIN() as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF($C$11:$C$16 = C$4,$B$11:$B$16,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with a subscription to Office 365 Excel.

[image]